# User Interface for creating Oracle SQL Loader control file

Tags: oracle, ide, sql-loader

Is there a good user interface for authoring Oracle SQL Loader control files? PL/SQL Developer includes a "Text Importer" feature (that reminds one of the Excel import wizard) to import text files into tables, but uses a proprietary format instead of the SQL Loader format. Something like this for the SQL Loader format would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 3):

TOAD has an interface to do SQL*Loads, it can generate the control files too...

http://www.toadsoft.com/get2know9/#Loader

Answer (score 1):

The TOAD answer is probably the best at present. However, in trying out the TOAD SQL Loader wizard, I was disappointed at the level of usability. It assumed that I had a pre-existing table to load the data into. I was looking for something that would let me first

- locate columns in the fixed-width input file, then
- analyze the columns for candidate names and data types, then
- generate a table *and* control file for loading the data

Since I couldn't find anything that would adequately meet my needs, I created a utility for the purpose. The utility is somewhat custom to my specific needs (fixed-width file format, headers on top, dashed divider separating headers from data, white space between columns) and only supports the SQL Loader features that I required. If I have opportunity to flesh it out to something more universally usable, I'd be happy to post it for the community.